# PHP как читать из переменной построчно?

Tags: php, переменные

Из РНР запускаю python-скрипт, результат сохраняется в переменной. Далее мне нужно прочитать содержимое переменной PHP построчно (есть символ перевода строки) чтобы удалить лишние строки. Не могу найти решение, смог только через сохранение в файл и повторного чтения файла fgets. Не красиво как-то. Какой принцип чтения значения переменной "построчно" ?

Comment: Чтобы читать из переменной построчно, надо разбить её в массив. по тому самому символу перевода строки

Comment: `$array_str = explode(PHP_EOL, $result_from_python]);` или `$array_str = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $result_from_python]);`

Comment: но вообще, формально на вопрос отвечает функция strtok()